# How to change parent variable from child component in angular2

Tags: angular, events

my parent component html:

```
<app-calendar-component [view]="calView" [callback]="calendarOptions" ></app-calendar-component>
<app-weekdetails-component *ngIf="test"></app-weekdetails-component>
```

my parent component ts:

```
public test:boolean=false;
```

appCalendarComponent:

```
ngOnInit(){
Calling services here and using data, after this process I need to set 
my variable test to be true which is defined in parent component.
}
```

So I need to set variable **test** to be true when 1st child(appCalendarComponent) is initialized.

Comment: usuly, i use some output inside my child component to interact into the parent variable. 
But will your variable be used elsewhere? if so you may use some service to define those variables with maybe some obsever + subject tricks to get it automaticaly inside your parent component

Answer (score 5):

You should use output way to comunicate with the parent component.

On the child:

```
import { Component, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Output() componentInit = new EventEmitter<>();

ngOnInit(){
Calling services here and using data, after this process I need to set 
my variable test to be true which is defined in parent component.

//After init
 this.componentInit.emit();
}
```

On the parent:

HTML:

```
<app-calendar-component 
                  (componentInit)="componentInitialize()" 
                  [view]="calView" 
                  [callback]="calendarOptions">
</app-calendar-component>
```

TypeScript:

```
componentInitialize():void{
 this.test = true;
}
```